# Using two different text sizes in one legend in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib

I have a legend on a graph in Python which is:

```
plt.text(sigma1+5,5,str("$\sigma$("+"%.2f"%(sigma1) + ",0)"),color='red')
```

I'd like the symbol sigma to be larger than the rest of the text. Is this possible? Or do I have to create two separate legends?

Comment: I assume this is a question about [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot)? If so, you should tag it appropriately and make it clear in the question.

Comment: As a side note, why are you calling `str(…)` around something which is a `str` already?

Comment: @abarnert Because `Explicit is better than implicit.` (I'm jk)

Comment: I have an equation defined as sigma1, so without the string it didn't work. I'm new to programming so please let me know if that is incorrect! Also, yes this is a question about matplotlib

Comment: @StormHayward: It doesn't matter if `sigma1` is a string; `"…"%(sigma1)` is going to be a string anyway. The string formatting operator can't return anything but a string. (And then concatenating that string and another one, the `",0)"`, will of course also give you a string.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, a [`matplotlib.text.Text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) instance uses a single style (font, size, etc.) for the whole string. So yes, I'm pretty sure you're going to need to create two of them.

If you don't know how to set the font size, see the docs for [`matplotlib.pyplot.text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text): you can either pass an optional `fontdict` argument that specifies font properties, or you can pass extra keyword arguments like `size` or `fontproperties` that get passed on to the `Text` constructor.